# Behavior near the regular point of a smooth vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

I'm reading Warner's *Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie groups* and come up with some trouble in understanding the proof of the theorem about the regular point of a smooth vector field. Here are the statement and the proof:
[image]

I barely understand the last part of the proof. I don't understand why we can know $d\sigma$ is non-singular by just computing the values of the differential at each tangent vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i}|_0$ in $T_0\mathbb{R}^n$. I mean we don't really know what $\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i}|_0$ is for $i\geq 2$, do we? Also, I don't understand why, by choosing the new coordinate system, we can obtain $d\sigma \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r_1}|_\left( t,a_2,\cdots,a_n\right)\right)=X_{\sigma \left( t,a_2,\cdots,a_n\right)}$ and thus we obtain the conclusion.

Any help or comment are hugely appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:

> I don't understand why we can know $d \sigma$ is non-singular by just computing the values of the differential at each tangent vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i}$ in $T_0\Bbb{R}^n$

The differential $d \sigma$ is a linear map. It is just a basic fact from linear algebra that if the images of basis vectors under a linear map are linearly independent, then the map is non-singular.

Second:

> I mean we don't really know what $\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r_i} \right|_0$ is for $i \geq 2$, do we?

I assume $r_i$ are the standard coordinates on $\Bbb{R}^n$, so that the $\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i}$ are just the standard coordinate vector fields on $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Lastly:

> Also, I don't understand why, by choosing the new coordinate system, we can obtain $d \sigma \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r_1} \right) = X_{σ(t,a_2,⋯,a_n)}$ and thus we obtain the conclusion.

Maybe you will have to look in your book at what Corollary (a) of 1.30 says, but the proof says that this implies that $\sigma$ is a coordinate map (in other words, $t,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are local coordinates near $m$). It is noted earlier in the proof that $d \sigma \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r_1} \right|_0 \right) = X_m$. To see why this is true not just at zero, think back to what the parameter $t$ represents:

You take the surface defined by the equation $y_1=0$, and what $\sigma$ does is "flow" the surface for time $t$ along the vector field $X$. Since $t$ is the first coordinate (corresponding to $r_1$), $d \sigma \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r_1} \right)$ is the vector field pointing in the $t$-direction. In other words, it points along the flow lines of $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response! I'm wondering if it's right that I think $d\sigma$ is non-singular this way: $d \sigma \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r_1}|_0 \right) =X_m$ since $X_t$ is a integral curve of $X$, and for the rest of $\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i}|_0$, note that $X_0\left(m\right)=m$ and thus $d\sigma \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r_i}|_0\right) =\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}|_m$. Hence $d\sigma$ is non-singular.

Comment: Yeah $r_i$ is the standard coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^n$ here, which I should have written in my last comment. Btw, I guess $d\sigma \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial r_1}|_\left(t,a_2,\cdots,a_n\right)\right)=X_{\sigma\left( t,a_2,\cdots,a_n\right)}$ is because for any fixed $p$ in the smooth manifold $M$ with coordinate $\left( 0,a_2,\cdots, a_n\right)$, we have $X_t\left(p\right)$ is an integral curve of $X$ and thus $X_t'\left(0\right)=X_p$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Thanks again!! I've been stuck on it for the past few days lol.